# How to change background color of readonly field in edit form

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid does not allow to change background color of readonly field in edit form.

There is style

```
.jqgrid-readonlycolumn {
    background-color: #FFFFDD;
}
```

which is specifed in colmodel editoptions:

```
editable: getReadOnlyEditable,
editoptions: { "readonly" : "readonly" , "class" : "grid-decimal-edit jqgrid-readonlycolumn" }


  function getReadOnlyEditable(options) {
if (options.mode === "cell" || options.mode === "add" || options.mode === "edit") {
    return false;
    }
// form editing
return "readonly";
 }
```

jqgrid adds those classes as first classes :

```
<td class="DataTD">
<input type="text" readonly="" 
   class="grid-decimal-edit jqgrid-readonlycolumn FormElement
          ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" 
    disabled="disabled" 
    id="Varadokumn" name="Varadokumn" role="textbox"></td>
```

after those classes `ui-widget-content` class appears which sets background color back to white.

How to fix this so that `jqgrid-readonlycolumn` class background color can used ?

**Update**

I tried to add style

```
body .DataTD .jqgrid-readonlycolumn {background-color: #FFFFDD !important;}
```

but background is still white

Comment: Does this style gets over ridden when you inspect the element?

Comment: No. This style is applied. For unknow reason `ui-widget-content` disables this style. After removing `ui-widget-content` class using Chrome developer tools proper background appears. Unfortunately, jqgrid generates classes in this order and so this change cannot applied permanently.

Comment: you could try using !important in the jqgrid-readonlycolumn class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough just to add `background-image: none`. Try to use

```css
.jqgrid-readonlycolumn {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #FFFFDD;
}
```